# How to implement Dijkstra Algorithm for finding shortest path from 1 node to all other in an undirected graph in C and print the distances as well

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

There is an undirected graph. You need to store all edge weights in a two-dimensional array cost[][], and calculate the shortest distance from the source node 0 to all other nodes. Suppose there are at most 100 nodes. If there is no edge between two nodes, we set their weight to a very large number, MAX_DIS=999999, to denote these two nodes are not connected directly.

In this exercise, you are required to fulfill the following two tasks.

1. Initialize Cost Array
   Initially, we have the array cost[100][100] to store the edge cost. We input the total nodes number n and edges number m, and the input all edges with <x,y,w> format, where w is the weight of edge (x,y). If there is no edge between two nodes, we set the cost MAX_DIS.
2. Calculate Shortest Distance.
   With the cost array, we need to compute the shortest distance between node 0 and all other nodes. Also, we need to initialize the distance array distance[100] at first. Then in each loop, we first find the min distance distance[w] and update other distance distance[v] if node v is adjacent to w.

//Below is my code for this challenge, but it is not working properly for all the test cases. It  works fine for some but I can't figure out where is the problem. I hope this is a good challenge to be solved and that is why I am posting it here. Can you guys help me debug this code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_NODES 100
#define MAX_DIS 999999


int cost[MAX_NODES][MAX_NODES];
int distance[MAX_NODES];

void initial(int m, int n);

void Dijkstra(int n);


void initial(int m, int n)
{
   /*
   let user input all edges and their weights and initialize   cost[][].
   note that if no edge between (x,y), set cost[x][y]=MAX_DIS
        and cost[a][b]=cost[b][a] for the undirected graph. 
       Fill in your code here...
   */
 int i,j;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
   for(j=0;j<n;j++){
     cost[i][j] = MAX_DIS;
   }
 }
 cost[0][0] = 0;
 int weight,x,y;
 for(i=0; i < m; i++){
   scanf("%d %d %d", &x,&y,&weight);
   cost[x][y] = weight;
   cost[y][x] = weight;
 }

}

void Dijsktra(int n)
{
   /*
       Fill in your code here...
       calculate the distance from node 0 to all other nodes.
   */
   int i;
   int S[n];
   S[0] = 1;
   
   int all_visited = 0;
   for(i=1;i<n;i++){
     S[i] = -1;
   }

   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     distance[i] = cost[0][i];
   }

while(all_visited != 1){
 int temp = MAX_DIS;
   int pos = -1;
   for(i=1;i<n;i++){
     if(S[i] == -1 && cost[0][i] <= temp){
       temp = cost[0][i];
       pos = i;
     }
   }

   S[pos] = 1;

   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     if(S[i] == -1)
       break;
   }
   
   if(i==n)
   all_visited = 1;

   for(i=1; i<n; i++){
     distance[i] = (int)fmin(distance[i], distance[pos] + cost[pos][i]);
    }
}
}

int main()
{
   int m,n;

   printf("Input the number of nodes:\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("Input the number of edges:\n");
   scanf("%d",&m);
   printf("Input these edges:\n");
   initial(m,n);
   Dijsktra(n);
   
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   printf("%d ",distance[i]);
   return 0;
}
```

This is test case for which my code is failing -

Input the number of nodes:
8
Input the number of edges:
10
Input these edges:
0 1 2,
1 2 9,
2 3 4,
3 5 7,
2 4 8,
5 6 10,
6 7 8,
7 5 1,
7 3 4,
0 4 10

Expected output - 0 2 11 15 10 20 27 19

My output - 0 2 11 15 10 999999 999999 999999

Comment: Please share input, expected output ans actual output of a failing test

Comment: OT: Don't use global variables

Comment: Decide for one language, not C and C++. Run your code through an autoindenter, so that it is formatted consistently. Not only does it attract readers here, it also helps you spot errors yourself more easily. In general, you should extract a [mcve] and include that in your question, along with input (unless you can hardcode it), expected output and actual output. BTW: The name is Dijkstra, not Dijsktra!

Comment: @4386427 I have added the output as you asked in the question. Please take a look now.

Answer (score 0):

use a `break` statement in this loop.

```
for(i=1;i<n;i++){
 if(S[i] == -1 && cost[0][i] <= temp){
   temp = cost[0][i];
   pos = i;
   break; //here
 }
}
```